# How to click on the center of an element c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am quite new to selenium and c# and I having an issue clicking on this element:

```
<i _ngcontent-ldd-c264="" class="close ms-icon iconms-cancel02 fixCloseModal">
 <::before>
```

I have tried to find the element with the class and xpath, but whenever i try to click i am not able to.

```
IWebElement CloseCard = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("fixCloseModal"));
CloseCard.Click();
```

Above is the example of trying to find the element with the class name.
I get this exception: "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable".

Inspecting with chrome, the button that needs to be clicked is highlighted on `"::before"`.
The line before with the class is highlighting the outline of the clickable area.

Apologies if the issue is not clear, please let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the page you are working on?

Comment: Unfortunately no because is a page only accessible by the company i am working for. Thank you for helping me with the edit of the post by the way.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: OK. Is `fixCloseModal` class name unique i.e. presented in that element only?
And anyway, Selenium can't click on pseudo elements. So you can click on `i` element, but not on the `before`

Comment: I just saw, the class name is not unique. The best choice here would be using xpath?

Comment: We can't say what is the best choice and what is the unique locator of the element without seeing the page DOM

Comment: I understand. I just tried with the XPath and i managed to get it working. Thank you very much and sorry for my "beginnerness"!

Comment: You don't need to know where is the center of an element to click it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if the page is in the process of shifting around as it is re-rendered. An explicit wait can help solve the problem:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var closeCard = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".fixCloseModal")));

closeCard.Click();
```